# Yii2 Assets does not work with IIS Server

Tags: php, windows, iis, yii2

I install yii2 application with composer on IIS Server with PHP Fast CGI Module.
I have also give full control permissions on

```
project_name\assets
project_name\runtime
project_name\web\
```

to both **IIS_USERS** ans **IUSER**

but when I try to access via browser

PHP code runs well but none of the assets file are loading.

When i checked log the following error occured.

```
Configuration Exception: The directory is not writable by the Web process 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project_name\web/assets
```

PS: Same code is running successfully with Apache Server in WAMP Stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem got solved. But dont know how.

Actually I enabled all the services if IIS through 
          Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Turn on or off windows Services.

And it works.

To debug the issue.. I even try fresh installation of the project. But didn't give that error.

Hope it will solve somebody's problem. 
By the way Thanks for your considering my Question.

Answer (score 1):

In my setup, I'm using Windows Authentication.

So I've first added **Everyone** to the assets folder and it's worked.
Then I've looked and discovered that the owner of the newly created assets subfolders was the **authenticated windows user**.

My not nice solution:

- Add full rights to **Authenticated Users**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error

```
C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ project_name \ Web / assets
```

why assest is preceded by

```
/ instead of \
```

maybe it's a problem formatting path